# unable to give value to a scalar from command line in perl

Tags: perl

I am trying the following perl code:

```
 use strict;
 use warnings;
 use Scalar::Util ("looks_like_number"); 
 my $color;
 if (undef $color)
 {
 my $color = $ARGV[0];
 }
 print "$0\n";
 print "$ARGV[0]\n";
 my @colors = ("blue", "yellow", "brown", "white");
 print "Please select a num:\n";
 foreach my $i (0..$#colors)
 {
 my $j = $i+1;
 print " $j $colors[$i]\n"; 
 }

 my $num = <STDIN>;
 chomp($num);
 if (looks_like_number($num) and defined $colors[$num-1])
 {
 $color = $colors[$num-1];
 }

 else
 {
 print "Bad Selection\n";
 }
 print "selected color is $color\n";
```

I want to select any number for the corresponding color choice or I should be able to provide a value of color by $color variable through command line, I am trying to run it in windows cmd using ' perl [C:/scriptname.pl] [color] ' but its not taking the argument but when I am printing ARGV[0] it is showing the argument being passed correctly. so what is the issue with my 'if (undef ARGV[0])' statement that its not getting executed.

Answer (score 2):

You are declaring the variable `$color` twice:

```
 my $color;
 if (undef $color)
 {
     my $color = $ARGV[0];
 }
```

The second `my $color` will create a second binding of the name `$color` and the value you assign to it and that binding will not be visibile outside of the scope, the enclosing curly brackets.

The expression

```
 if (undef $color)
```

does not do what you intend it to do. [undef](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/undef.html) will always set a value to `undef`. You want to use [defined](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/defined.html) instead.

After applying those two changes, the code could look like:

```
 my $color;
 if (! defined $color)
 {
     $color = $ARGV[0];
 }
```

Comment: That's good answer, but that `if` is still redundant - `$color` isn't initialized, so it's always undefined, so that code could be simplified to `my $color = $ARGV[0];`

Answer (score 0):

```
my $color;
if (undef $color)
{
my $color = $ARGV[0];
}
```

This looks rather strange. In line 1 you declare a scalar variable called `$color`. In line 2, you call [`undef()`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/undef.html) on that variable which replaces the contents of `$color` with `undef()` (that's unnecessary as a newly-declared Perl scalar will always contain `undef()`). This expression will return `undef`, which is false, so the code in your `if` block is never executed.

In line 4, you declare a new variable, also called `$color` and set that to `$ARGV[0]`. There are two problems with this. Firstly, that line will never be executed for the reasons explained in the previous paragraph. And, secondly, your new `$color` variable will cease to exist once you leave the block, so you would never see the effect of this change.

I think the main problem here is that you have confused [`undef()`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/undef.html) with [`defined()`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/defined.html). `undef()` will always give a variable an undefined values, but I suspect you wanted `defined()` which tells you whether or not a variable contains a defined value.

What you probably wanted was:

```
my $color;

if (!defined $color) {
  $color = $ARGV[0];
}
```

Which can be written as:

```
my $color //= $ARGV[0];
```

But it's still slightly confusing as it's not clear why you think `$color` could ever be defined immediately after being declared.